# How to use Windows permissions mechanism?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, authorization

I just started learning about WCF and I need to write a chat program with Winforms.

I need to create a local users group (with Windows) that will have the permissions to use that chat program. Users that not in the group cannot use it.
I have read about it but I still don't understand what do I need to do in the server side for this authirization, and how I make sure only users from this specific group have the permissions.

Comment: Are you intending to deploy this, or use it in one organization?  Either way, the approach that you are taking sounds difficult to support... If it's within a single organization, I would let the sysadmin handle it manually rather than trying to set this from code.  If it is for deployment, you are likely to have better luck by using a traditional user login, or by tying into something like Azure AD for authentication.

Comment: I know it is something with the service Authorization and behaviors on the web.config and maybe sessions.

Comment: I'm sure that WCF includes that feature, but be aware that using groups like this would only apply to a single domain (ie - a workplace network).  People generally have admin rights on their own personal computers, so they can add themselves to whatever group they want, and if the computers aren't in the same domain as the server, then I think they are different "groups" even if the local groups have the same name.  On the client side, this stuff would all be in the System.Security.Principal namespace, if that helps any.  You can check a user's security groups with those classes.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you are looking for, although I repeat the warning that this approach will only work within a single domain (which typically means it's good for intranet only):

[WCF Web Service Authentication based on AD groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330995/wcf-web-service-authentication-based-on-ad-groups)

The accepted answer demonstrates how to capture the security context of the user making a request to the service, by drilling into this object to determine group membership:

```
WindowsIdentity caller = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

You would need to use a wsHttp or netTcp binding (as opposed to the basic HTTP binding) to get this to work - these binding mechanisms offer more features in exchange for less interoperability with other platforms.  If you are strictly "inside the firewall", the netTcp binding typically makes more sense, although it may use ports that a firewall would block by default.  wsHTTP uses standard HTTP ports, which are usually open.

On the client side, there are equivalent objects in System.Security.Principal namespace that would allow you to enforce security policies there as well.